# Results Per Page

Tags: c#, pagination, webforms

Whenever I am in a specific page (ex. Page Number 6) and I select from the Results Per Page Drop-Down List (ex. From 20 to 50) the total page would then change from (ex. 9 to 3).

However! The specific page that I am currently on (Page 6) is out of bounds of the Total Page (ex. total page = 3, my current page = 6). It will then display nothing and I have to click the button backwards just to reach the last page of the new Results Per Page list.

I have created a code to specify where the Session["curr_page"] should be whenever this happens. However, I could not determine where to put this code, since it does not fire whenever I change the results per page drop down list. Here is the code that I made.

```
if (Convert.ToInt16(Session["curr_page"]) > Convert.ToInt16(Session["total_page"]))
    {
        Session["curr_page"] = Session["total_page"];
    }
```

Here is the sample source code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadPageSizer();
        LeadStatusDDL();
        Session["curr_page"] = 1;
        BindAndPage();
    }
    OnPageLoad();
}

private void BindAndPage()
    {
        rptLeadsPager.DataSource = ListLeads(ddlLStatus.Text.ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(Session["curr_page"]), Convert.ToInt16(ddlPageSize.Text));
        rptLeadsPager.DataBind();
        BuildPagination(Convert.ToInt16(Session["total_page"]), Convert.ToInt16(Session["curr_page"]), 10);
    }
private void OnPageLoad()
    {
        rptLeadsPager.DataSource = ListLeads(ddlLStatus.Text.ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(Session["curr_page"]), Convert.ToInt16(ddlPageSize.Text));
        rptLeadsPager.DataBind();
        BuildPagination(Convert.ToInt16(Session["total_page"]), Convert.ToInt16(Session["curr_page"]), 10);
    }
#region SQL Stored Procedure
private DataTable ListLeads(string leadStatus, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    int searchResultsCount;
    DataSet dsSearchResults;

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlConnection"]))
    {
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("LeadsPager", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //add parameters
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeadsStatus", leadStatus);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageNumber", pageNumber);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResultsPerPage", pageSize);

            var resultsCountParam = new SqlParameter("@SearchResultsCount", SqlDbType.Int);
            resultsCountParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(resultsCountParam);

            using (var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
            {
                dsSearchResults = new DataSet();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsSearchResults);

                searchResultsCount = int.Parse(resultsCountParam.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    if (searchResultsCount == 0)
    {
        ResultHeader.Visible = false;
        ResultFooter.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Session["total_page"] = GetTotalPage(pageSize, searchResultsCount);
        lblTotalPage.Text = Session["total_page"].ToString();
        ResultHeader.Visible = true;
        ResultFooter.Visible = true;
    }

    RenderToolbar();

    if (dsSearchResults.Tables.Count > 0)
        return dsSearchResults.Tables[0];
    else
        return null;
}
#endregion
```

Thank You.

Comment: Try putting it just before OnPageLoad() in the Page_Load event.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: Ok. Put it in the ListLeads() method just after where you are setting the Session["total_page"] = GetTotalPage(pageSize, searchResultsCount);